# Is "Even I too." a valid sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Consider the following conversations:

> A: "I must leave now because I have to be home in 30 minutes."
>   B: "Even I too."
>
> A: "I am getting bored."
>   B: "Even I too."

1. Is the response valid? I want to know the validity of the expression grammatically, not if it can be replaced by a better response.
2. If the response is valid, what are some other possible scenarios where it can be used?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to express? The word *even* seems a bit cryptic. is the message simply *me too*?

Comment: Maybe in some places that response would be used.  But not here where I live.   We would say "Me, too".

Comment: @bib Yes the message is "I/Me, too". It didn't seem right when a friend said that to me. I know "Me, too" would be better but is this expression grammatically correct?

Comment: Is OP a native speaker? I've never heard anyone say *"Even I too"*. Most people would simply say *"Me too"*, though I do recognise that some native speakers (particularly, *Jewish Americans?*) might *append* an almost meaningless ***even*** the way they do with ***already***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *I too* portion of your sentence makes sense and is grammatical. It means

> I too [must leave now].

However, this sounds very stilted, and in shortened form, *me too* is much more common. Some might argue that this latter expression is ungramatical, but it could easily be expanded to a grammatically sound

> That goes for me too.

The *[even](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/even)* makes little sense. As an adverb (which is this usage), it means

> Used to emphasize something surprising or extreme: *they wore fur hats, even in summer*
>
> or
>   Used in comparisons for emphasis: *he knows even less about it than I do*

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

There is nothing in the limited context that you offer for either example which would support the use of *even*. I could make up a context that would justify it

> A: "I must leave now because I have to be home in 30 minutes."
>
> B: "I had planned to stay, but now even I too must go."

Answer (score 0):

Today, I saw a friend’s FB post with the following sentence:

Saw my mom baking some potatoes few days back; I remembered that even I baked some potatoes n veggies last year

I told her that usage ‘even I baked’ isn’t quite right. Instead I suggested:

Saw my mom baking some potatoes a few days back; I remembered that I too had baked some potatoes n veggies last year

Comment: "*I told her that usage ‘even I baked’ isn’t quite right.*" Unfortunately, you have given bad advice. Your firend wrote correctly. Here "even" is used correctly for emphasis.

Comment: I thought Manmohan was entirely right, Greybeard.

How is "I too had baked …" bad?

How is "even I baked …" not bad, in this context?

"even I baked …" doesn't emphasise a shared need or reaction, as to go or to be bored, but only the unlikelihood of the action.

"Cooking was such a craze that even I baked, who wouldn't normally boil an egg" does give emphasis, but not as in the Question.

Even there, "I too" is complete in itself and "Even I too", too much. 

Don't you think the whole topic belongs in English Language Learners?